# With akka http, how can I inject request headers into an incoming route in the server?

Tags: scala, http, request, header, akka

In my server, which is using akka http, I'd like to mark certain routes with an attribute, or a custom HTTP request header, that is accessible to downstream processing of that request.  How can I do this?  I see how to extract the request, but I don't see how to modify that request in a way that is passed along.

For example, my route might be something like

```
val route = (get & path("yay") {
  complete(...the actual processing of the route...)
}
```

and I'd like to mark this route with a property (attribute, request header, etc) accessible to "the actual processing of the route".

(I'm highly simplifying my example.  In my real code, that route processing is not something I could just simply pass, say, a value directly in this block of code.  So, I was thinking of being able to mark the request itself in some fashion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapRequest` for modifying the HttpRequest:

```
val route = mapRequest(...modifying the request...) {
  complete(...the actual processing of the route...)
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  Thanks!